# Change the Marker Icon to a custom Icon | Mapbox SDK

Tags: android, mapbox, marker, mapbox-android

I have two *.geojson-files in my assets-folder and I am loading these points to the map. But I am trying to change the default mapbox-markers to custom colored ones (e.g. green and black markers).

I created a marker as a vector asset, but when I use that instead of "R.drawable.map_marker_light" I get the following error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference`

I couldn't find a current solution for my problem.

```
public void GeoJSONToMap(final String sourceId, final String layerId, final String asset_id) {
        mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

                try {
                    GeoJsonSource source = new GeoJsonSource(sourceId, new URI(asset_id));

                    style.addSource(source);

                    Bitmap icon;


                    if (layerId.equals("first-layer-id")) {
                        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default);
                    } else {
                        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map_marker_light);
                    }

                    style.addImage(layerId + " marker", icon);

                    SymbolLayer symbolLayer = new SymbolLayer(layerId, sourceId);

                    symbolLayer.setProperties(
                            iconImage(layerId + " marker"),
                            iconAllowOverlap(true),
                            iconIgnorePlacement(true)
                    );

                    style.addLayer(symbolLayer);

                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution through github. I added the following code to my MainActivity and
adjusted the if-else part. Then I got my custom markers.

```
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.marker_book, null);
        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);

        if (mBitmap != null && mBitmap.getConfig() != Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) {
            mBitmap = mBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
        }
        return mBitmap;
    }
```